# How to install Laravel dependency Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel?

Tags: php, laravel

I wrote a [package](https://github.com/adiafora/laravel-cron-schedule) extending the Laravel scheduler. `Adiafora\Schedule\Kernel` class extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel`.

But I don't understand what dependency should I specify in `composer.json` to install the `Illuminate\Foundation\Console` package?

I use Laravel 8.

Comment: The replace secion of [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/composer.json#L48) of laravel has a list of packages it replaces. Add all the ones you use in your composer.json. Since you are using foundation classes I think you can't avoid requiring the entire `laravel/framework` though

Comment: @apokryfos It seems that this is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using this composer command:

```
composer require laravel-foundation/console
```

Comment: Its best to use what Laravel uses, which is this package [illuminate/console](https://github.com/illuminate/console)

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. This is a third-party package, and my package is intended for installation in the Laravel project.